# Webアプリケーションでの操作ログの取得方法

Tags: javascript, html

Webアプリケーションでの操作ログの取得方法について伺いたいです。

というのも、通常のシステムであればユーザがどのような操作をしたか、どのようなデータを入力したか
といったものを操作ログとして出力していると認識しています。（デバッグ、トラブル対応のため）

しかし、Webアプリケーションのフロント側（特にJS)ではコンソール画面にログを出力する機能はあっても操作ログをファイルとして出力することは一般的で無い様に見受けられます。
特に業務で利用するようなシステムの場合、（例えばWrikeのようなもの[Wrike](https://www.wrike.com/ja/)）では、ログを取得しない場合、後々トラブルが起きた際に面倒なことになると考えています。

そこで下記についてお伺いしたいです。

1.Webアプリケーションのフロント側のログを収集する方法があまりないのか。
　調べても、choromeへconsole.logを出す方法しか見つからず、ログを収集し後で確認出来るような形で保存するといった方法は見つかりませんでした。
2.操作ログやコンソールログを収集をする場合、どのような方法で行うのか。
　操作する度にjsonファイルかなにかを発行し、それをサーバへ送るとかでしょうか。

イメージとしては下記のようなシステムを想定しています。
◇利用シーン
　・業務利用システム
　　（ゲーム等ではなく、ある特定のユーザのみが利用するようなものです）
◇システム構成
　・HTML/CSS/JS

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: フロントの操作を全部サーバーに送る仕組みもありますよ。一般的ではないかもしれませんが、やるところはやっています。お客さんが見ている画面と同じ画面をカスタマーサポートが見られるように使ったりします。

Comment: 想定されているWebアプリケーションや「操作」ログとは具体的にどういうものなのかもう少し明確にしてください。例えば昔ながらのページ遷移型のアプリケーションとブラウザゲームでは全く話が違ってきます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。>Noguchiさん　そうなんですね。仕組みとしては一からフルスクで書くような形でしょうか。　>suzukisさん　想定していたwebアプリはブラウザゲーではなくいわゆるWrikeのような業務利用の仕組みを考えていました。（そこまで具体的なものというより仕組みとして調べてもやり方が見つからなかったため皆さんどうしてるのかと考え質問させて頂いた次第です）[Wrike](https://www.wrike.com/ja/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の聞き方が“一般的か”・“普通は”と抽象的で、このサイトには向きません。

> 1.Webアプリケーションのフロント側の操作ログを収集するのはなぜ一般的でないのか。

ブラウザ側でjavascriptでログを生成することは、必要があれば有り得るのではないでしょうか。ただし、ローカルに保存できたとしてもその方法は一般的ではないでしょう。Webアプリケーションの運用者からは確認のしようがないですから。
（そのログはどこかに送信する必要があり、送信先で格納・分析できなければ活用には程遠いです。自作するにはそれなりの手間がかかるはずです。）

> 2.操作ログやコンソールログを収集するとしたら普通はどのような形で収集するのか。

"操作ログ"や"コンソールログ"が何を指すのか具体的に示してもらえるとよいですが、↓のようなサービスは参考になるのではないでしょうか。
（下記のサービスを利用することが“普通”であると言える知見は私にはありません）

New Relic Browser
https://newrelic.com/browser-monitoring
http://qiita.com/kumatronik/items/35f82746d5072001f566

Microsoft Azure Application Insights 
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/application-insights/app-insights-javascript

Comment: 一般的といった言葉を使ってしまいすみません。イメージとしては業務システムのような利用者が限定されるようなものをイメージしていました。（ECサイトは利用者が多すぎて、取らないだろうなと納得出来たため）　操作ログについては、ボタン押下やデータ入力内容といったもの。コンソールログはJSのconsole.logで出力されるようなものを考えていました。

Comment: “イメージ”していたものを質問に記入してください。また、イメージしていた回答と相違があればコメントしてください。

Comment: >htbさん　すみませんでした。修正しました